# How to not enable toggle class at first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#summary").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
<div id="summary">
  <div class="clicked">111</div>
  <div class="clicked">222</div>
</div>
```

How to not set beckoned-color to red when html page load.Only change it to red when click on its div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `class="clicked"` from your divs?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#summary").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
<div id="summary">
  <div>111</div>
  <div>222</div>
</div>
```

Comment: XDDD..looks like I ask a stupid question.Now , I know how to use toggleClass.

Answer (score 2):

You have already added the `.clicked` to the divs when your page is loading, while you want to toggle the class by clicking on the `div`. Try the below code:

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#summary', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
<div id="summary">
  <div class="someclass">111</div>
  <div class="someclass">222</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the inline class `clicked` from the div tags

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="summary">
  <div >111</div>
  <div >222</div>
</div>
```

**Live demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/qjrahp6t/**

Answer (score 0):

Remove class `clicked` from the HTML. It will become red only after the click.

```
<div id="summary">
  <div class="">111</div>
  <div class="">222</div>
</div>
```